# Tratar Mensagem de Erro - Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Como posso tratar a mensagem em anexo via trigger?

Preciso impedir um insert/update e exibir apenas a frase "Dr(a) por gentileza, preencha uma data de previsão da alta."

```
INSTEAD OF INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @SEMPREV CHAR(1)

SELECT @SEMPREV = SEMPREVISAO FROM INSERTED


IF @SEMPREV = 'S'
  begin
  PRINT 'Dr(a) por gentileza, preencha uma data de previsão da alta.'; 
  ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
  return;
  end;

END;
```

]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fU4I6.png)

Comment: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/22177.t-sql-error-handling-within-triggers.aspx

Answer (score -1):

Você pode utilizar o comando [THROW](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/language-elements/throw-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

```
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER trigger01 
   ON  dbo.tab1
   INSTEAD OF INSERT, UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SEMPREV VARCHAR(50)

SELECT @SEMPREV = name FROM INSERTED

IF @SEMPREV = 'S'
    THROW 50002, N'Dr(a) por gentileza, preencha uma data de previsão da alta.', 1; 
END
GO
```

A comando `THROW` causará o encerramento do lote de instruções.

Ao executar o `INSERT` com o valor `'S'` no campo de interesse:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[tab1]
           ([name])
     VALUES
           ('S')       
GO
```

Retornará a o seguinte erro:

```
Msg 50002, Level 16, State 1, Procedure trigger01, Line 10 [Batch Start Line 3]
Dr(a) por gentileza, preencha uma data de previsão da alta.
```

Fazendo o INSERT com [tratamento de erro](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/language-elements/try-catch-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16):

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON;    
DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(400);     
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRAN
        INSERT INTO [dbo].[tab1] ([name]) VALUES ('S'); 
    COMMIT;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE(); 
    PRINT @ErrorMessage;
    IF (XACT_STATE()) = -1
        ROLLBACK;
    IF (XACT_STATE()) = 1
        COMMIT;   
END CATCH;
```

Como resultado, teremos:

```
(0 rows affected)
Dr(a) por gentileza, preencha uma data de previsão da alta.
```

Comment: Certo, este comando impediu o insert e exibiu a mensagem. O problema é a mensagem q ele exibe antes, imagem que anexei na abertura.
Eu consigo tratar esse texto?
Ocorreu um erro no sistema
MSG: GENERAL SQL ERROR

Comment: Você tem que tratar o erro na sua aplicacão cliente. Como no exemplo acima "Fazendo o INSERT com tratamento de erro" que simula uma aplicação cliente onde o erro será capturado pelo bloco CATCH. Esse erro tem q ser capturado na camada de aplicação.